# Como inserir aspas simples dentro de aspas simples html

Tags: html, html5, string, input, placeholder

Preciso que o placeholder da minha tag input seja "Patient's Name" e graças ao script que está sendo usado, eu não posso por aspas duplas. Gostaria de saber como eu posso inserir uma aspa simples dentro de duas aspas simples.

Segue o código:

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='patientsName' id='patientsName' placeholder='Patients Name'>
```

Como eu queria que fosse:

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='patientsName' id='patientsName' placeholder='Patient's Name'>
```

Se alguem puder dar um help aí

Comment: script de qual linguagem você usa ? Tente algo do tipo `placeholder='Patient\'s Name'`

Comment: As pessoas do stack overflow Brasil tem que para de negativar pergunta quando não sabe responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o caractere de escape `&#39;` que refere-se à aspas simples `'`:

```html
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='patientsName' id='patientsName' placeholder='Patient&#39;s Name'>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou!!!